# Find and get first valid image url from array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have mainImage and array of images. I need to check if mainImage is available first, if it's not, then I need to find first valid image in array of image urls and set it to image src. how can I achieve this?

`const imageSrc= () => { const validImg = images.find(image => image.url); return mainImage?.url || validImg }`

I need something like that to return main image if it's available or first resolved image from array.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `{mainImage && ArrImg.find(i=>i.url)}` Zura can you please add your tried code or it will get deleted

Comment: Define *available*. Do you mean it will resolve to an actual image if tried? If so you need to load each URL, and stop on the first that does not throw an error.

Comment: Yes, main image is sometimes available, but if it's not then I need to find valid image from array of image urls and finally set it to image src attribute. P.S main image doesn't live in images array

Comment: Ok, have you tried anything to that effect? If so please provide your attempt and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: I tried find method, but I don't know how to check if image exists on certain url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [react-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image) and pass the array of the urls as src.